# What is the regex pattern for comma, space plus a certain word?

Tags: java, regex

I need to split a string using Java's split() method. How to write the regex pattern for delimiters that is a certain word? For example, "and"?

I got the pattern for splitting space and comma which is `[,\\s]` but I want to add the word, `and` so that it also becomes a delimiter.

I tried many combinations including `[,\\s]|(and)` but no luck.

Comment: `[]` defines a character class. `[,\s]` means "a single character that can be EITHER a space or a comma. If you want "comma followed by space", then it shouldn't have the `[]`, just `,\s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure without an input and desired output, but you could change your last pattern to something like: `\\s(?!and|,)|\\s*,\\s*|\\s+and\\s+`.

For instance:

```
String toSplit = "Blah,blah, foo ,bar and blah again";
System.out.println(
    Arrays.toString(
        toSplit.split(
//            ┌ whitespace not followed by "and" or ","
//            |           ┌ or
//            |           | ┌ 0/more whitespace, ",", 0/more whitespace
//            |           | |       ┌ or
//            |           | |       |┌ 1/more whitespace, "and", 1/more ws
//            |           | |       ||
             "\\s(?!and|,)|\\s*,\\s*|\\s+and\\s+"
        )
    )
);
```

**Output**

```
[Blah, blah, foo, bar, blah, again]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
String[] toks = input.split( "\\s*\\band\b\\s*|[,\\s]" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternation operator. Here is a [sample program](http://goo.gl/OSnBLF):

```
String string = "My mother and I";
String[] parts = string.split("(?:[,\\s]|and)");
for (int i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(parts[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
My                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
mother                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 


I
```